# Algorithm to generate integer not contained in a file of 4 billion integers,1 GB memory

Tags: java, algorithm

Can somebody please explain how this algorithm works?

```
int radix = 8;
byte[] bitfield = new byte[0xffffffff/radix];

void F() throws FileNotFoundException{

Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("a.txt"));

while(in.hasNextInt()){

    int n = in.nextInt();
    bitfield[n/radix] |= (1 << (n%radix));
}

for(int i = 0; i< bitfield.lenght; i++){
    for(int j =0; j<radix; j++){
        if( (bitfield[i] & (1<<j)) == 0) System.out.print(i*radix+j);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `I went through all the explanations on stackoverflow` Which one(s)?

Comment: The solution which included sorting the file and adding one to the largest integer.(But sorting is not an option because the size of the file is 16MB and I cannot copy it into an array)
Another solution which said add one bit to the longest integer.(Thats not possible as it may cause overflow)
And one more solution from Pearls of programming which I did not understand.

Comment: @sanashariff I think the original commenter wanted you to edit your question to include links to what you have already looked at, and perhaps explain what you do understand about it. There's a guide to asking good questions, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask read that to understand why people might downvote this ( I didn't downvote but I can see why others do) by explaining what you have done it shows some effort and helps us understand what knowledge level you have, so answers can be more targeted and appropriate. Good luck!

Comment: If the other solutions aren't suitable they are therefore irrelevant. What you're really asking here is how does this specific algorithm work. I would just delete the first sentence. The downvoting seems excessive.

Comment: Oh okay.. I will be more specific when asking questions

Answer (score 1):

It works by forming essentially a `BitSet` of the integers that are in the file, and then scanning the set for the first unused value. It's more space-efficient than an array of booleans.

Comment: The level of detail hardly rises above a comment. I would gladly upvote the answer if you elaborate more.

Comment: @EJP from your answer I understood
1.An array of 2^32 bits is created, name bitfield
2.The file is read and for each number that is found the bit is set to 1
3.Scan through bitfield array and the first bit that is found set to 0 is the integer that is not present 

My doubts are:
1.How does (1<<(n%radix)) work to achieve that
2.How exactly does each step in  the for loop work